# plutus-playground-client npm start error (MacOs Intel i7)

Tags: plutus, plutus-pioneer-program, macos

[Updated]

```
✖ ｢wdm｣: ERROR in Error: Child compilation failed:
  Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '/Users/fanik/development/plutus_pioneer_program/plutus-apps/plutus-playground-client/undefined/static/index.html' in '/User  s/fanik/development/plutus_pioneer_program/plutus-apps/plutus-playground-client'
  ModuleNotFoundError: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '/Users/fanik/development/plutus_pioneer_program/plutus-apps/plutus-playground-client/undefined/static/  index.html' in '/Users/fanik/development/plutus_pioneer_program/plutus-apps/plutus-playground-client'
  
  - Compilation.js:1765 
    [plutus-playground-client]/[webpack]/lib/Compilation.js:1765:28
  
  - NormalModuleFactory.js:730 
    [plutus-playground-client]/[webpack]/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:730:13
  
  
  - NormalModuleFactory.js:273 
    [plutus-playground-client]/[webpack]/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:273:22
  
  
  - NormalModuleFactory.js:402 
    [plutus-playground-client]/[webpack]/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:402:22
  
  - NormalModuleFactory.js:117 
    [plutus-playground-client]/[webpack]/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:117:11
  
  - NormalModuleFactory.js:646 
    [plutus-playground-client]/[webpack]/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:646:24
  
  - NormalModuleFactory.js:800 
    [plutus-playground-client]/[webpack]/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:800:8
  
  - NormalModuleFactory.js:920 
    [plutus-playground-client]/[webpack]/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:920:5
  
  - child-compiler.js:169 
    [plutus-playground-client]/[html-webpack-plugin]/lib/child-compiler.js:169:18
  
  - Compiler.js:536 
    [plutus-playground-client]/[webpack]/lib/Compiler.js:536:11
  
  - Compiler.js:1103 
    [plutus-playground-client]/[webpack]/lib/Compiler.js:1103:17
  
  
  - task_queues.js:95 processTicksAndRejections
    internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5

1 ERROR in child compilations (Use 'stats.children: true' resp. '--stats-children' for more details)
webpack compiled with 2 errors
```

I had tried the below guides to reinstall several times, but still cannot connect server

https://github.com/renzwo/cardano-plutus-apps-install-m1/blob/main/README.md

http://blog.punkbit.com/hacking/plutus-developer-environment-setup-on-macos-monterey/

**git repo that I tested:**

41149926c108c71831cfe8d244c83b0ee4bf5c8a

7f53f18dfc788bf6aa929f47d840efa1247e11fd

6aff97d596ac9d59460aab5c65627b1c8c0a1528

**My recent setting:**

/etc/nix/nix.conf

```
build-users-group = nixbld
experimental-features = nix-command
substituters        = https://hydra.iohk.io https://iohk.cachix.org https://cache.nixos.org/
trusted-public-keys = hydra.iohk.io:f/Ea+s+dFdN+3Y/G+FDgSq+a5NEWhJGzdjvKNGv0/EQ= iohk.cachix.org-1:DpRUyj7h7V830dp/i6Nti+NEO2/nhblbov/8MW7Rqoo= cache.nixos.org-1:6N$
```

Stack 2.7.3

HLS   1.5.1

cabal 3.6.2.0

GHC   8.10.7

nix (Nix) 2.5.1

macOS Monterey 12.1

```
[PASS] PATH contains only one nix version.
[PASS] All profiles are gcroots.
[PASS] Client protocol matches store protocol.
```

Server status

```
plutus-playground-server: for development use only
[Info] Running: (Nothing,Webserver {_port = 8080, _maxInterpretationTime = 80s})
Initializing Context
Initializing Context
Warning: GITHUB_CLIENT_ID not set
Warning: GITHUB_CLIENT_SECRET not set
Warning: JWT_SIGNATURE not set
Interpreter ready
```

[image: seems server did not work]

Comment: I'm running into issues too with my macbook 2015 macOS Monterey i7.  Did you ever get it to work?

Comment: Found this helpful link also for my macOS i7 install.
https://github.com/Til-D/cardano-plutus

Comment: Sorry for a late reply, I gave up on mac installation and installed virtualbox to figure out the playground

Comment: https://github.com/FanikIsLearning/ubuntu-plutus/blob/main/README.md

Comment: If you want this question answered, please upvote it or put a bounty on it (if you have enough reputation).

Comment: No I don't have enough reputation. But I think I figured out the installation with virtualbox and ubuntu. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to run `GC_DONT_GC=1 npm start`

We're working on improving this UX going forward, but many community members have been able to get this to work with this flag.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I tried this comment on mac as well, but still do not work. Therefore, I gave up installation on mac and shifted to ubuntu, which works right there.

Comment: https://github.com/FanikIsLearning/ubuntu-plutus/blob/main/README.md