# Child compilation failed

Tags: plutus-pioneer-program, plutus-playground, nix-shell, nixos

Hello Cardano community.

This question has been asked in the community and I would like to resurface it as I am having the same problem.

Ref: [plutus-playground-client npm start error (MacOs Intel i7)](https://cardano.stackexchange.com/questions/6500/plutus-playground-client-npm-start-error-macos-intel-i7)

There is not a resolution yet for this post and I am wondering if anyone in the community has anything additional to add.

I received this same error and I've included the error log below.
Using
VM VirtualBox
NixOS

Any help you could provide would be much appreciated.

ERROR in Error: Child compilation failed:
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '/home/sidney/plutus-apps/plutus-playgr  ound-client/undefined/static/index.html' in '/home/sidney/plutus-apps/plutus-p  layground-client'
ModuleNotFoundError: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '/home/sidney/plut  us-apps/plutus-playground-client/undefined/static/index.html' in '/home/sidney  /plutus-apps/plutus-playground-client'

- Compilation.js:1765
  [plutus-playground-client]/[webpack]/lib/Compilation.js:1765:28
- NormalModuleFactory.js:730
  [plutus-playground-client]/[webpack]/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:730:13
- NormalModuleFactory.js:273
  [plutus-playground-client]/[webpack]/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:273:22
- NormalModuleFactory.js:402
  [plutus-playground-client]/[webpack]/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:402:22
- NormalModuleFactory.js:117
  [plutus-playground-client]/[webpack]/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:117:11
- NormalModuleFactory.js:646
  [plutus-playground-client]/[webpack]/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:646:24
- NormalModuleFactory.js:800
  [plutus-playground-client]/[webpack]/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:800:8
- NormalModuleFactory.js:920
  [plutus-playground-client]/[webpack]/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:920:5
- child-compiler.js:169
  [plutus-playground-client]/[html-webpack-plugin]/lib/child-compiler.js:169:1    8
- Compiler.js:536
  [plutus-playground-client]/[webpack]/lib/Compiler.js:536:11
- Compiler.js:1103
  [plutus-playground-client]/[webpack]/lib/Compiler.js:1103:17
- task_queues.js:95 processTicksAndRejections
  internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5

1 ERROR in child compilations (Use 'stats.children: true' resp. '--stats-children' for more details)
webpack compiled with 2 errors and 1 warning
ℹ ｢wdm｣: Failed to compile.

Comment: Upvote the existing question.  Duplicate questions get closed & deleted.

Comment: Welcome to Cardano SE! As a new user be sure to take the [Tour].